# SQL query for to find item with a specific attribute and related non-foreign keyed items

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to write a sql query to return a list of items that have a specific attribute and that are also referenced by a non-foreign-keyed item. To expound, let's say table one is cars, and it has a registration status. Table two is parking permits, which has a non-foreign-keyed field of car_id that is an int representing car ids. I want to return a list of cars that have a registration status of 'active' and at least one permit bearing its id.

I've tried different combinations of inner and left joins combined with wheres, but I can't get it to return what I am needing.

Would there be a way to count the number of permits returned by a join for each car? Or is there a simpler way that I am missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomH I'm always looking to improve myself, so I'm glad to have the criticism regarding my questions, but could you be specific as to what I should improve on with my question rather than simply posting a like to the how to ask page?

Comment: The page lists everything that I could say. Provide table structures, sample data, expected output, your own attempt(s) and what was wrong with their results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

SELECT cars.*

FROM   cars

WHERE  cars.reg_status='active'

  AND  EXISTS (SELECT *

               FROM   permits

               WHERE  permits.car_id=cars.car_id);

This should return all cars with status active and having at least 1 permit

By the way: if the 'permits' table refers to the 'cars' table by means of a car_id, I strongly recommend to create a foreign key

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. I hadn't consider the use of exists.

Comment: Also, I completely agree about creating a foreign key. It's a legacy code base and I haven't gotten to it yet, but it's on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a JOIN and count the matching ids:-

```
SELECT a.car_id
        COUNT(b.permit_id)
FROM cars a
INNER JOIN parking_permits b
ON a.car_id = b.car_id
WHERE a.registration_status = 'active'
GROUP BY a.car_id
```

If you wanted to include those without any parking permits in the list:-

```
SELECT a.car_id
        COUNT(b.permit_id)
FROM cars a
LEFT OUTER JOIN parking_permits b
ON a.car_id = b.car_id
WHERE a.registration_status = 'active'
GROUP BY a.car_id
```